# Why is "out" used instead of "cout" when overloading the "<<" operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am learning operator overloading.  "out" is being used instead of "cout" when overloading "<<" operator. I don't understand why.

```
  ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const IntList &L ) {
    out << "[ ";
    for (int k=0; k< L.numItems; k++) {
    out << L.Items[k] << ' ';
    }
   out << ']';
}
```

I want to ask differences between cout and out and what happens if I use cout instead of out.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Because cout is already the name of another object?

Comment: Where is your **return out** ? Did you miss it out while posting it here ??

Comment: I suggest you replace `out` with `wibble` and see what happens. You see the name *doesn't matter*.

Comment: @user1559792 You have received many great answers. Any reason why you don't accept any?

Answer (score 15):

What you are looking at is a overloaded "stream insertion" operator, allowing some custom class to be written to an `ostream` object using the typical `cout << myObject` syntax.

The variable in this case is called `out` because that's the name they've given to the `ostream` object being passed into the function, which may be *any* output stream, whether it's `cout` or an `fstream` or a `stringstream`. It's just a variable name, and they could have called it `blah` and written:

```
ostream &operator<<( ostream &blah, const IntList &L ) {
   blah << "[ ";
   // ...
}
```

Typically you choose a variable name which is descriptive, and `out` as a name for an output stream is pretty descriptive.

`cout` would be an especially *bad* variable name, as it is strongly associated with `std::cout`, used for writing specifically to the standard output stream. This code doesn't write specificially to standard output, it writes to *any* `ostream` object via the `<<` operator so they've chosen a more generic name for their `ostream` argument.

Comment: There is also an element of convention to this, in that it is an output stream, but not necessarily cout.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to ask differences between cout and out and what happens if I use cout instead of out. Thanks for answers.

In this case, an `ostream&` (`out`) is a parameter passed to the function.  This allows the `operator<<` to work on *any* `ostream`.

[`cout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) is a *specific* `ostream` instance - the standard output stream.  If they used `cout` here, you wouldn't be able to use the `<<` operator on `cerr` (the standard error stream) or any other `ostream`.  If you replaced the `out` with `cout` in the body, any time you used this on a different ostream, it'd be written to `cout`. (Of course, if you changed the parameter to be named `cout`, that wouldn't happen - but it would be very misleading to anybody looking at this code, as people would *expect* that the code writes to the standard output stream, not to the stream being passed in.)

In general, you only would want to use `cout` as a name if you are specifically referring to `std::cout` - the standard output stream, as using it in other contexts would be very confusing.

Comment: "If they used cout here, you wouldn't be able to use the << operator on cerr" - that's not actually true... `cout` - used as the parameter name - would not clash with `::std::cout`, but it would certainly be misleading.

Comment: @TonyD Yeah - I tried to add something to that effect (was writing when you posted that) because I realized it wasn't clear.

Comment: @TonyD I was trying to suggest if you left the parameter name the same, but used cout in the method body.

Comment: fair enough - that would be a pretty awful thing to debug!  Cheers

Comment: This business of using `cout` in the body of the function is another reason why `using namespace std;` is an accident waiting to happen. As soon as any of your chosen variable names can be typoed as a standard name that you've brought into scope, there's a risk that your typos will compile. Use `out` for the variable and `std::cout` for STDOUT, I say :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop True - Using `cout` as a name in general, though, would just be a poor choice.  But, since that the OP mentioned using `cout` (and not `std::cout`), I assume they're already `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1):

out is the name of the ostream object passed to the overloaded operator (inside the implementation of the operator).

The overloaded operator allows you to write code like this

```
IntList i;
cout<<i;
```

or

```
cerr<<i;
```

In the implementation if you substituted *out* with *cout*, then the second call

```
cerr<<i;
```

would print to standard output whereas it should have printed to standard error.

Answer (score 0):

The critical thing here is really the types in the function signature: as long as it's a freestanding function with two parameters - one of type `std::ostream&` and the other able to be matched by the value to be streamed, then the function body will be invoked.  It should return  a reference to the stream to allow chaining (as in `if (cout << firstIntList << secondIntList)`).

The actual parameter names are whatever you feel like, as long as they're not reserved words.  I tend to use "os", as in output-stream.

Comment: "os" is too long a name. I tend to use ostream & o.

Comment: @user93353: yeah, good point - I'll just update all my code ;-P